# Unable to click on element on webpage via xpath and no errors thrown

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to test a website's form submit page. The submit button has the following HTML:

```
<input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SubmitButton" class="SubmitButton" type="submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SubmitButton", "", true, "", "", false, false))" value="Submit" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SubmitButton"/>
```

I've located it by id and am running the below code in my test. For some reason there are no errors thrown. The test just passes without the button ever being clicked. What am I missing here?

```
self.click(10, 
           "id", 
           OigHotlinePageMap['SubmitButtonId']
           )
```

I have the click() method stored in a page object:

```
def wait_until_element_clickable(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element

 def click(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
    self.wait_until_element_clickable(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).click()
```

I have the locator stored in a UI map dictionary:

```
OigHotlinePageMap = dict(SubmitButtonId = "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SubmitButton"
)
```

Comment: The element is not in an iframe either, otherwise I could have tried that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the onclick() in the HTML was not firing because one of the radio buttons on the website was not chosen. I was able to click on the submit button after selecting the required radio button.

A regular click() method worked via CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the class name instead, it shall work :

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'SubmitButton')
```

for which you shall introduce this inside `wait_until_element_clickable` to your code :

```
if locatorMode == LocatorMode.CLASS_NAME
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, Locator)))
```

and then use it as :

```
self.click(10, "class", OigHotlinePageMap['SubmitButtonClass'])
```

where in now you can have your dictionary changed to :

```
OigHotlinePageMap = dict(SubmitButtonClass = "SubmitButton")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same issue when using class name. No errors, just no action taken by click(). Perhaps it has something to do with javascript and the onclick()?